# Override all requests from javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have an asp.net application. I need to implement that every request to the server for a page will contain an additional parameter in query string. My idea was to capture all reqests in javascript and add this parameter.

I might use jQuery selector for every link and change it href and override jquery ajax to add this parameter to request but this is not the best solution.

Is this possible in JS ?

Thanks,
Bartek

Comment: I'm curious why you need this?  A cookie isn't sufficient?

Comment: The only way to do it would be the way you have already suggested; modify all anchor tags, then modify the url param in the ajax calls.

Comment: @gilly3 Session and cookies are shared between tabs. I need to add an id to query parameters to specify the context

Answer (score 2):

You can add event handlers to each link on the page:

```
//use jQuery 1.7's `.on()` to bind the event handler
$('a').on('click', function (e) {

    //stop the default click from happening
    e.preventDefault();

    //setup the extra query-string parameter
    var extra = '?your_extra=true';

    //if the link clicked already has a query-string then use an ampersand rather than a question mark
    if (this.href.indexOf('?') > 0) {
        extra = '&your_extra=true'
    }

    //direct the user to the requested page
    window.location = this.href + extra;
});
```

You can use the `beforeSend` function to alter AJAX requests before they are sent: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: This needs to be modified slightly. As it is, if your link has a query-string already, it will become `?oldquery=foo&your_extra=true?your_extra=true`.

Comment: I believe it will work fine. If no query-string is found then it uses the default value of the `extra` variable and if a query-string is found then it overwrites the default value to use an ampersand.

Comment: I assume this would happen on document ready. What about dynamically loaded html?

Comment: You can use `.on()` like the depreciated `.delegate()` like this: `$(document).on('click', 'a', function () {...})` and you can replace `document` with any parent element of the links that is in the DOM when this code is parsed.

Answer (score 1):

For anchor tags it'll be as simple as;

```
$(document).delegate('a', 'click', function() {
    this.href = (this.href.indexOf("?") > -1 ? '&' : '?') + 'magicParam=4';
});
```

If you're using jQuery 1.7, you can do;

```
$(document).on('click', 'a'function() {
    this.href = (this.href.indexOf("?") > -1 ? '&' : '?') + 'magicParam=4';
});
```

If you want to consider forms, AJAX requests etc, you'll have to manage them separately. Of course, if you have an `window.location.href = blahblahblah`, these won't be catered for either.

If you want to handle AJAX requests, jQuery has a nice `beforeSend` method which you can add to your [`jQuery.ajaxSetup`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup) to modify all the `url`'s you target.

Comment: wouldn't you want to use a click event instead of keydown?

Comment: @AbeMiessler: Yes, not sure *why* I typed that :P

Comment: I assume this would happen on document ready. What about dynamically loaded html?

Comment: @bodziec: No, because we're using event delegation, this will work for all dynamically added elements as well.